# How to prevent duplication in update statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have documents like this in my MongoDB collection:

```
my_dict = {"chat": 1, "entity": 2, "count": 55}
```

I need to update them and if the document does not exist **(entirely)**, then insert a new one:

```
results_collection.update_one(my_dict,
                    {"$set": {"chat": 1,
                              "entity": 2,
                              "count": 60}},
                    upsert=True)
```

But if the document exists, it is duplicating it! it should just update because `chat` and `entity` are the same. But it is inserting a new one.
So, I will be having two similar documents with differences in `count` only.

See how this is duplicated in the picture [image],

I want the new one to replace the above one.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the matching document. In your case, you can do it by the identical fields:

```
results_collection.update_one(
  {'chat': my_dict['chat'], 'entity': my_dict['entity']},
  {'$set': {'count': 60}},
                    upsert=True)
```

The code in the original question is using `my_dict` to try to find the matching document to update, but `my_dict` includes the `count`, thus never finds the document and thus creating a new one...

Comment: Life saver! What a legend. 
OMG how I didn't think about that? I thank you !!!

Comment: Please help, I'm retrieving these documents from collection `A` and storing them in this collection `B` (in the picture above). So the `count` depends on how I'm receiving it from `A`.
If the count was 2 in `A`, it will be 2 in `B`. But if the document was deleted entirely from `A`, it is staying in `B` as 2 !! Please help me to make the update 100% real in all cases. @nimrod serok

Comment: 1. Instead of deleting, you can change the count to `0`. 2. Why are using 2 collections for the same data and updating both? It is better to use one collection for each data type...not to save the same data twice

Comment: Exactly, how can I make it 0 when the document is deleted from `A` ? And why do I use 2 collections because I'm asked like that :( @nimrod serok

Comment: I mean when the document is deleted from `A` the count in `B` should be 0. but it cannot be below 1 how can I do that Sir?

Comment: If you must use two collections, when you get the event of changing the count just update collection `A` and `B`. Use `$inc`, instead of `$set`, in order to increase or decrease the count

Comment: `pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {chat: "1"}, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 14, 'errmsg': 'Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {chat: "22"}'}
` I know `chat` is string but can I cast it simply as int? because I can't change it that way @nimrod serok

Comment: The `"1"` should be cast to int: `1`

Comment: Python is not accepting that because see in the picture `chat` and `entity` are `str`. No way to solve that ? :(

Comment: This should not be a problem. Check out [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BCbh2M6_QzD)

Comment: I mean they are `str` in collection `A` not `int`

Comment: Look at [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M5Qn-Po2fYx)

Comment: Does not work :(  It is doubling the count (if it was 3 it will become 6 !) and not decrement at all. @nimrod serok

Comment: You need to increment by `1` on any insert and by `-1` on every remove event

Comment: I appreciate your effort <3 but that is incrementing without considering `chat` and `entity`.
All I need is, if `count` for `chat` and `entity` was 3 in `A`, then increment the document count by 3 in `B`. That is it.